# Url parameters not get in my views in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to add and edit in same template. Url showing parameters but id showing none still in my views.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_supplierdetails/1

IN My Template:

```
{% for supplier in suppliers %}

<a href="{% url 'edit_supplierdetails' supplier.id %}">Edit</a>
```

IN My URL

```
url(r'supplierdetails/', views.add_supplierdetails, name='add_supplierdetails'), 
url(r'^edit_supplierdetails/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.add_supplierdetails, name='edit_supplierdetails'),
```

In My Views:

```
def add_supplierdetails(request,  id=None):

    print(id)
    brands = SupplierDetails.objects.all()
    if id:
        productcategory = get_object_or_404(SupplierDetails, id=id)
        title = 'Update'    
    else:
        productcategory = SupplierDetails()
        title = 'Add'

    form = SupplierDetailsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=productcategory)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Brand "+ title +" successfully") 
        return redirect('/brand')
    return render(request, 'products/add_supplier2.html', {
        'form': form,
        'suppliers': brands,
        'title': title
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modify the url it's working.

```
url(r'supplierdetails/$', views.add_supplierdetails, name='add_supplierdetails'), 
url(r'^supplierdetails/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.add_supplierdetails, name='edit_supplierdetails'),
```